# Почему не отображается карта гугл сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api

Почему не отображается карта гугл на сайте хотя на denwer все работает отлично

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не указали API ключ при подключении API

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Ваш ключ"></script>
```

Про ключ можете узнать здесь: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Все равно не работает(

Comment: В консоли всё написано. Теперь ошибка: The Google Maps JavaScript API is not activated on your API project. You may need to enable the Google Maps JavaScript API under APIs in the Google API Console.
Нужно зайти в консоль и включить Google Maps JavaScript API в консоли